# Input value not changing until click on page

Tags: jquery

Currently I have this:

js

```
$(function() {
    if(window.Touch) {document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
        $('.field1').val('Shorter Value');
    },false);}
});
```

The value of ".field1" is currently "Longer Value" but not until I click (tap in mobile) does it change to "Shorter Value"

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your requirement? On page load you want to change it?

Comment: Well, why do you put the code in the addEventListener callback if you want it to be executed immediately ?

Answer (score 1):

That's what you told it to do - it's happening when the `touchstart` event is triggered.

If you want it to happen at page load when `window.Touch` is true, say:

```
$(function() {
    if(window.Touch) {
        $('.field1').val('Shorter Value');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hard to guess why without seeing working code, knowing when/where .field1 is created, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `addEventListener`, you ask for the browser to execute the callback when the event arises (here the `touchstart` event).

If you want to execute the code immediately (more precisely as soon as the DOM is ready), don't use `addEventListener` :

```
$(function() {
    if(window.Touch) {
        $('.field1').val('Shorter Value');
    }
});
```